# Check pytesseract version using python

Tags: python, python-tesseract

Is there a way to check pytesseract version in python?
According to [PyPi documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) of pytesseract, there is a built-in function `get_tesseract_version` to get pytesseract version. But when I run it in python, I get the following:

```
>>> import pytesseract
>>> pytesseract.get_tesseract_version
<function get_tesseract_version at 0x7f4b9edd4598>
>>> print(pytesseract.get_tesseract_version)
<function get_tesseract_version at 0x7f4b9edd4598>
```

I know that I can get pytesseract version using `pip freeze`, but I want to get it using python. Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call the function – `pytesseract.get_tesseract_version()` – but that will get you the underlying *Tesseract* version, not the version of `pytesseract` in use.

Since `pytesseract` doesn't unfortunately expose the standard `__version__` variable, you can use the `pkg_resources` API to introspect the current package environment:

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.working_set.by_key['pytesseract'].version
'0.3.0'
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the function parenthesis and you should get the output:

```
pytesseract.get_tesseract_version() 
5.0.0-alpha.20200328
```

Comment: If you check the accepted answer "pytesseract.get_tesseract_version() – but that will get you the underlying Tesseract version, not the version of pytesseract in use" it is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with pip, simply type the following command inside your environment:

> pip freeze

All installed packages (in that environment) and their corresponding versions will be listed:)